# How to prevent Asp.Net MVC session mixing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies, azure-web-app-service

Our ASP.Net MVC application is hosted on Azure. recently, one of our user reported issue that he is able to see data related to other user. we tested this on our 3-4 laptops and could able to replicate. this scenario happened 2-3 times but not frequently. It is strange. we were still not able to find out root cause of this issue. we are not using output caching technique. we are using Forms Authentication and session timeout kept open for 30 minutes only. we also didn't use any static variable to store session.

On Azure, we have traffic manager profiles implemented. there 2 instances of these application exists and priority was set accordingly so as to up one instance when other gets down.

when checked code, We found below code from Global.asax but don't know exact usage of this code. it could be issue but not sure 100%. when debugged, this gets called every time when action is executed.

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["RecycleCheck"] == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("RecycleCheck", "1", null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        appendLogFile("Recycle Took Place");
    }

    if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null || Session["CurrentUser"] == null) return;
    HttpContext.Current.User = (CustomPrincipal)Session["CurrentUser"];
}
```

How session gets mixed? is there bug in Azure IIS Server or we are missing something in our code? how to avoid session mixing?

Comment: Have you enabled ARR Affinity in azure app service? If not then enable it and check. refer screenshot for how to enable (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz3xV.png )

Comment: @RohitPatel checked. it is ON.

Comment: Issue still exist..this is scary..

Comment: Can someone intercept user session? and how it is possible? I found this issue occasionally but couldn't find root cause